# Processor load percentage for individual processors using WMI Class Win32_PerfFormattedData_Counters_ProcessorInformation

Tags: windows, cpu, wmi, processor

I am using "Win32_PerfFormattedData_Counters_ProcessorInformation" WMI class to read processor information. I want to collect the load percentage for each individual processor from this WMI class "Win32_PerfFormattedData_Counters_ProcessorInformation". But this class returns the output based on cores like ( 0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0._Total, _Total) instead of processors like ( CPU0, CPU1 ).

[Win32_PerfFormattedData_Counters_ProcessorInformation WMI Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5bmK.png)

*Note: We previously tried using the "Win32_Processor" class. But in some machines, it always gives the load percentage as 100 even though the actual usage of the processor is less. So we are relying on this alternative WMI class.*

How to find out which core belongs to which processor from this "Win32_PerfFormattedData_Counters_ProcessorInformation" WMI class?

(or)

Any Other WMI class other than "Win32_Processor" will give Load percentage info of Individual processors ?